# What is the relevance of bootstrapped confidence intervals on markov chain transition matrices?

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, bootstrap, markov-process

Am I right in thinking that bootstrapping is just replicating your original data x amount of times?

So I have a series of $n=20$ sequences of varying length containing the letters ACGTE.
The probability of having C after to A is

$$
P(X_C=x_C|X_A=x_A),
$$

and which can be calculated from the set of sequences, thus
$$
\widehat{P_{ij}}=\displaystyle \frac{x_{ij}}{\sum^mx_{ik}}\quad \text{where m=ACGT or E}.
$$

Assume this is $\widehat{P}\rightarrow P$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. However I don't have enough sequences to produce a full transition matrix $P$, instead I have a sparse matrix:
 \begin{align}
\widehat{P}=&\begin{pmatrix}
  0&         0  &       0&    1.00&         0\\
         0&         0 &   0.22&    0.44&   0.33\\
         0&    0.19&    0.57&    0.10&    0.14\\
    0.03&   0.19&    0.09&    0.50&   0.19\\
         0&    0.06&    0.13&   0.56&    0.25\\
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{align}

This source suggests that I can use bootstrapping to increase my sample size and get a better approximationg of $P$: [arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4131v1.pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4131v1.pdf)

However, what does this really tell me? Nothing more useful if I don't have more real data right? How do confidence intervals (http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/46/88/04/PDF/estimvar_final.pdf) make it credible all of a sudden?

Comment: Bootstrapping doesn't make numerous copies of your original data, no. The simple bootstrap takes samples (with replacement) from your original data, on the basis that the best available estimate of the distribution, $F$, is the empirical distribution, $\hat F$. Bootstrapping doesn't add information you don't have (it *doesn't* 'increase your sample size' in any sense), but as suggested, does let you get some idea of the sampling uncertainty associated with estimates.

Comment: I looked at your linked citation. The term 'bootstrap' doesn't appear in that paper.

Comment: @Glen_b I understand, thank you. Could you comment on how I might calculate a confidence interval for the values in $\widehat{P}$ using this method? It seems to me that all the entries are related in some way and would not follow a standard normal distribution, but a multivariate one. Any thoughts how one would account for this?

Comment: @DWin many apologies: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4131v1.pdf The citation I used was for variance of $\widehat{P}$

Comment: HCAI, edit the correct link into your post.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm best placed to answer that question (on uncertainty associated with $\hat P$) at the moment, but it looks like a good question.

Comment: @Glen_b Do you think you could point me to a good source?

Comment: If I had one, you'd know.